# telerik textbox selectAll() property does not work

Tags: wpf, silverlight, telerik

I want to select textbox's text when it got focus. I have found many links/ answers about "selectAll()" property and it does work. but the problem is that I have three inputs (a textbox, then combo box, then textbox) and i want to set selectAll() on 3rd input (means on 2nd textbox) when i come to that textbox through combobox, it does work but if i make comboBox disabled, it doesnot work, it just focuses there but does not select whole text.

I don't know why its happening? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you temporarily replace the second Telerik `TextBox` with a .NET `TextBox`, do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: I cant check that one in my application because of some other properties and checks etc.. but if I run application in debug mode, it selects whole text but in other case it does not. its really weird :S